# How to change the background color of a Button inside a webview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

I have a `WebView` that loads an URL (say `login.salesforce.com`) & asks the user to login to his instance.

Now, I want to get rid of the default login screen that it shows up & want to play around with the color of the login button.

Is it possible to change the color of a button inside a website that loads in `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`?

Comment: Not sure, but to me, it sounds impossible, because you are trying to use Xcode to style an element to which it has no access. I would try adding a custom button from Xcode's side, and try in placing it over or in place of the webpage's button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely Yes. For this you need to have little bit knowledge of html,css and java script.

Step 1. Prepare a java script as a string like below:

```
let changeHtmlbuttonScript = """
var property = document.getElementById(btn);
if (count == 0) {
  property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
  count = 1;
} else {
  property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
  count = 0;
}
"""
```

Step 2: Evaluate java script on your current webview

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(self.changeHtmlbuttonScript)
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same, changing the background color of button but this piece of code is not working. Can you please confirm if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with UIWebView if you override the resource loading with a custom NSURLProtocol, and load your own CSS instead of theirs. "evaluateJavaScript" might work as well if you wait until the page is loaded somehow (see other reply).

Most likely what you ask violates the Salesforce's terms of service, so I wouldn't do it.

If they have a REST API for something that you try to achieve, then you can provide your own UI.